# MKV video file not playing on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, stagefright

I was trying to play `MKV` video file on the `Lollipop` release but could not able to play, though it was working properly in `Kitkat` release.

My findings on debugging into the issue as below,

In the function [`ParseTrackEntry()`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/libvpx/libwebm/mkvparser.cpp#5722)

the default track settings for audio, video and content encoding is set to -1

If the id of the current track is not video nor audio but of type content_encoding, the track settings is updated accordingly.

Later in the function, the buffer is parsed based on the type of track, i.e if the track is of type video then audio track setting should be less than 0, [similarly if the track consist of audio the video track setting should be less than 0](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/libvpx/libwebm/mkvparser.cpp#5898).

But in case the track consist of content encoding type, there is a check for video, audio and content encoding track settings as well.

As the track settings will be updated in case of type content encoding, it fails here

```
if (e.start >= 0)
    return E_FILE_FORMAT_INVALID;
```

When the check for content encoding is removed the `MKV` file plays successfully.

My file has a `video` track, an `audio` track and multiple `subtitles`. What could be the issue? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue could be due to a missing check in `mkvparser.cpp`. In `ParseTrackEntry`, once a `TrackEntry` is identified, there are checks for `audio` presence in `video` packet and vice-versa.

Though the [`Matroska` file specification](http://www.matroska.org/files/matroska.pdf) (Ref: Page 21, comment before Table 8) specifies that this is also permissible, the current implementation reports an error.

When the `TrackEntry` element is not a `video` or `audio` i.e. `subtitle` or `metadata`, then the way `ContentEncoding` is handled has to be very clear. The check in this [line](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/libvpx/libwebm/mkvparser.cpp#5947) is valid for `metadata`. However, for `subtitle` track, the specification shows that `ContentEncoding` element can be present (Ref: Page 24 of standard above).

Hence, this check should probably become

```
if((info.type == Track::kMetadata) && (e.start >= 0))
    return E_FILE_FORMAT_INVALID;
```

With this change, for `subtitle` tracks with `ContentEncoding`, the processing would continue and your file should playback.

**P.S:** We may have to check with Google if they agree with this change.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for the explaination. I tried with the above check and its working fine.

Comment: Change is merged: https://gerrit.chromium.org/gerrit/#/c/73474/

Thanks for debugging this issue

Comment: @LajosMolnar.. Thank you. It's nice to hear from you after a long time :)